# What kind of network error is Chrome encountering when 'Status = (failed)' and 'Type = undefined'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-domain

Sometimes I randomly see network requests from Chrome failing with Status = '(failed)' (status code 0 from the request object in JavaScript) and the response type as 'undefined' . I cannot isolate why, my internet connection seems to be up and the same endpoint on the server works if requested from say cURL.

Viewing the request details does not show any more response information, only the request info.

I thought it might be missing CORS headers, but I have verified they are there and anyway on a CORS permission problem Chrome reports the status as '(cancelled)'.

Any thoughts? Is it just that the host is unreachable? Why does it seem that all retries from the web app also fail until the browser is restarted?

[image: (failed) request status text in Chrome inspector]

Comment: What's in the script main.js?

Comment: Its our minified web app's main source file.

Comment: What's requesting the main.js? Could you provide a more information on the use case.

Comment: Nothing is requesting main.js, this is the file making the requests. I decided not to include the actual end point URLs as they are internal. In Chrome the URI comes first, then the HTTP method, then the status code, the response type, then the script that made the request, then the response size and time. Sorry for the confusion. Im just wondering if anyone else has experienced this in Google Chrome.

Comment: Was this ever fixed? I'm encountering this issue, myself...

Answer (score 39):

I ran into this while working on an ad serving network. It ended up being the AdBlock Plus Chrome extension blocking any assets, probably the "ad" in the path. I whitelisted my domain and it worked.

Comment: Holy crap, that just saved me so much trouble.

Comment: Yep.  I use UBlock Origin, and wouldn't you know it - blocked a script from my OWN domain just because it had some ga event tracking code in it!

Answer (score 10):

This can occur when the size in Content-Length header is larger then the actual Content being submitted, chrome considers the request "failed" since it could not retrieve the entire document.

Comment: Ah interesting, thanks for the pointer! I will see if this is a possibility.

Comment: any progress on reproducing this ?

Comment: I agree. For those using Apache, this answer solved my problem: http://serverfault.com/a/393938/75718

Answer (score 6):

I began seeing these errors on a web page with a bad SSL certificate. I had already allowed the browser to proceed to the page, but after a while AJAX requests to the server would start failing. To fix the problem I would have to refresh the page in order to get back to the warning message so that I could accept it again and have my AJAX requests stop being blocked.

Unfortunately, in my case I haven't found the reason why Chrome forgets I want access to the domain. There is the `Remember decisions to proceed through SSL errors for a specified length of time` setting in `chrome://flags`, but it appears to have no affect.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this in an ASP.NET IHttpHandler because I was calling 
`context.Response.Close()` instead of `context.Response.End()`.  Wasn't quite closing the HTTP connection properly.  It didn't cause a problem in any browsers but Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

We had exactly this issue with an application reaching an API we control. It took a while for me to realize that slower clients were not seeing the issue, whereas faster clients (and pages with more requests) were.

It turned out that our HA Proxy was rate limiting requests on our frontend. Once we raised the limit from the value of 20 we had set up to something around 100, we no longer had the issue.

So it's possible you're getting blocked by something along the request pathway, potentially a proxy or load balancer or even a firewall.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the site I was working on had a Content-Security-Policy defined which I wasn't aware of, so appending to the CSP my new resource endpoint was the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when a cdn was being blocked by my isp. Flushing out dns worked for me. Refer [this](https://superuser.com/a/1553417/708839) for the how-to.

Answer (score -2):

In my case I have a Samsung laptop, and I unistalled **Samsung Support Service**, clear cache of Chrome and its works.