# What network error could be responsible for Status (failed) and type Pending in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers, wireshark, varnish

From time to time a site I'm maintaining get failed GET requests on some resources. The status is returned as (failed) and the type as Pending. The headers containg nothing more than the request itself, no response whatsoever.

The server is running Drupal and Varnish.

Any thoughts on what causes the failure or where to start debugging?

[image: Failed GET request in Chrome dev tools]

This might be related to [What kind of network error is Chrome encountering when 'Status = (failed)' and 'Type = undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125784/what-kind-of-network-error-is-chrome-encountering-when-status-failed-and) even though the type return a different message. Could someone maybe confirm this? If so, how could I debug this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT, I just installed wireshark to try to debug a bit more.**

Here's the entire followup on the failed request

[image: Wireshark screenshot]

**A dump of 94645, 94651, 94686 and 94688**

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
  94645 211.219995  192.168.0.101         85.134.37.196         HTTP     1192   [TCP Retransmission] GET /sites/default/files/css/css_4PXz_aZSHtm7FWHqYsMdm7sl9C4802BFn9tXlePfpJU.css HTTP/1.1 

Frame 94645: 1192 bytes on wire (9536 bits), 1192 bytes captured (9536 bits)
    Arrival Time: Nov  7, 2012 22:55:18.002267000 EET
    Epoch Time: 1352321718.002267000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.006199000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.815800000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 211.219995000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 94645
    Frame Length: 1192 bytes (9536 bits)
    Capture Length: 1192 bytes (9536 bits)
    [Frame is marked: True]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ip:tcp:http]
    [Coloring Rule Name: Bad TCP]
    [Coloring Rule String: tcp.analysis.flags]
Ethernet II, Src: HonHaiPr_e7:39:2f (38:59:f9:e7:39:2f), Dst: D-LinkIn_2f:a4:a4 (14:d6:4d:2f:a4:a4)
    Destination: D-LinkIn_2f:a4:a4 (14:d6:4d:2f:a4:a4)
        Address: D-LinkIn_2f:a4:a4 (14:d6:4d:2f:a4:a4)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Source: HonHaiPr_e7:39:2f (38:59:f9:e7:39:2f)
        Address: HonHaiPr_e7:39:2f (38:59:f9:e7:39:2f)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Type: IP (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.0.101 (192.168.0.101), Dst: 85.134.37.196 (85.134.37.196)
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)
    Total Length: 1178
    Identification: 0x4e23 (20003)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .1.. .... = Don't fragment: Set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0xabe3 [correct]
        [Good: True]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 192.168.0.101 (192.168.0.101)
    Destination: 85.134.37.196 (85.134.37.196)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51714 (51714), Dst Port: http (80), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 1126
    Source port: 51714 (51714)
    Destination port: http (80)
    [Stream index: 5205]
    Sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
    [Next sequence number: 1127    (relative sequence number)]
    Acknowledgement number: 1    (relative ack number)
    Header length: 32 bytes
    Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
        000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
        ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
        .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
        .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
        .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
        .... ...1 .... = Acknowledgement: Set
        .... .... 1... = Push: Set
        .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
        .... .... ..0. = Syn: Not set
        .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
    Window size value: 229
    [Calculated window size: 14656]
    [Window size scaling factor: 64]
    Checksum: 0xb15e [validation disabled]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
    Options: (12 bytes)
        No-Operation (NOP)
        No-Operation (NOP)
        Timestamps: TSval 30409363, TSecr 1723048723
            Kind: Timestamp (8)
            Length: 10
            Timestamp value: 30409363
            Timestamp echo reply: 1723048723
    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
        [Bytes in flight: 1126]
        [TCP Analysis Flags]
            [This frame is a (suspected) retransmission]
                [Expert Info (Note/Sequence): Retransmission (suspected)]
                    [Message: Retransmission (suspected)]
                    [Severity level: Note]
                    [Group: Sequence]
            [The RTO for this segment was: 1.480371000 seconds]
            [RTO based on delta from frame: 92823]
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    GET /sites/default/files/css/css_4PXz_aZSHtm7FWHqYsMdm7sl9C4802BFn9tXlePfpJU.css HTTP/1.1\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): GET /sites/default/files/css/css_4PXz_aZSHtm7FWHqYsMdm7sl9C4802BFn9tXlePfpJU.css HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Message: GET /sites/default/files/css/css_4PXz_aZSHtm7FWHqYsMdm7sl9C4802BFn9tXlePfpJU.css HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Request Method: GET
        Request URI: /sites/default/files/css/css_4PXz_aZSHtm7FWHqYsMdm7sl9C4802BFn9tXlePfpJU.css
        Request Version: HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.snellman.fi\r\n
    Connection: keep-alive\r\n
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4\r\n
    Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1\r\n
    Referer: http://www.snellman.fi/sv\r\n
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\r\n
    [truncated] Cookie: v_tid=82524dc4552b4cd4a22d1fa4e7e78d72; Drupal.toolbar.collapsed=0; ctools-collapsible-state=views-ui-advanced-column-uusimmat_reseptit%3A1%2Cviews-ui-advanced-column-Related%3A1; Drupal.tableDrag.showWeight=0; SESS4049
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: http://www.snellman.fi/sites/default/files/css/css_4PXz_aZSHtm7FWHqYsMdm7sl9C4802BFn9tXlePfpJU.css]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
  94651 211.228592  85.134.37.196         192.168.0.101         TCP      66     [TCP Dup ACK 92860#3] http > 51714 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=14592 Len=0 TSval=1723049571 TSecr=1723044620

Frame 94651: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits)
    Arrival Time: Nov  7, 2012 22:55:18.010864000 EET
    Epoch Time: 1352321718.010864000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.001166000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.008597000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 211.228592000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 94651
    Frame Length: 66 bytes (528 bits)
    Capture Length: 66 bytes (528 bits)
    [Frame is marked: True]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ip:tcp]
    [Coloring Rule Name: Bad TCP]
    [Coloring Rule String: tcp.analysis.flags]
Ethernet II, Src: D-LinkIn_2f:a4:a4 (14:d6:4d:2f:a4:a4), Dst: HonHaiPr_e7:39:2f (38:59:f9:e7:39:2f)
    Destination: HonHaiPr_e7:39:2f (38:59:f9:e7:39:2f)
        Address: HonHaiPr_e7:39:2f (38:59:f9:e7:39:2f)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Source: D-LinkIn_2f:a4:a4 (14:d6:4d:2f:a4:a4)
        Address: D-LinkIn_2f:a4:a4 (14:d6:4d:2f:a4:a4)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Type: IP (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 85.134.37.196 (85.134.37.196), Dst: 192.168.0.101 (192.168.0.101)
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)
    Total Length: 52
    Identification: 0x8b62 (35682)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .1.. .... = Don't fragment: Set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 58
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0x790a [correct]
        [Good: True]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 85.134.37.196 (85.134.37.196)
    Destination: 192.168.0.101 (192.168.0.101)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: http (80), Dst Port: 51714 (51714), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0
    Source port: http (80)
    Destination port: 51714 (51714)
    [Stream index: 5205]
    Sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
    Acknowledgement number: 1    (relative ack number)
    Header length: 32 bytes
    Flags: 0x010 (ACK)
        000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
        ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
        .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
        .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
        .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
        .... ...1 .... = Acknowledgement: Set
        .... .... 0... = Push: Not set
        .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
        .... .... ..0. = Syn: Not set
        .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
    Window size value: 114
    [Calculated window size: 14592]
    [Window size scaling factor: 128]
    Checksum: 0xd246 [validation disabled]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
    Options: (12 bytes)
        No-Operation (NOP)
        No-Operation (NOP)
        Timestamps: TSval 1723049571, TSecr 1723044620
            Kind: Timestamp (8)
            Length: 10
            Timestamp value: 1723049571
            Timestamp echo reply: 1723044620
    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
        [TCP Analysis Flags]
            [This is a TCP duplicate ack]
        [Duplicate ACK #: 3]
        [Duplicate to the ACK in frame: 92860]
            [Expert Info (Note/Sequence): Duplicate ACK (#3)]
                [Message: Duplicate ACK (#3)]
                [Severity level: Note]
                [Group: Sequence]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
  94686 211.305208  85.134.37.196         192.168.0.101         TCP      66     http > 51714 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=14592 Len=0 TSval=1723049647 TSecr=1723044620

Frame 94686: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits)
    Arrival Time: Nov  7, 2012 22:55:18.087480000 EET
    Epoch Time: 1352321718.087480000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000026000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.076616000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 211.305208000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 94686
    Frame Length: 66 bytes (528 bits)
    Capture Length: 66 bytes (528 bits)
    [Frame is marked: True]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ip:tcp]
    [Coloring Rule Name: HTTP]
    [Coloring Rule String: http || tcp.port == 80]
Ethernet II, Src: D-LinkIn_2f:a4:a4 (14:d6:4d:2f:a4:a4), Dst: HonHaiPr_e7:39:2f (38:59:f9:e7:39:2f)
    Destination: HonHaiPr_e7:39:2f (38:59:f9:e7:39:2f)
        Address: HonHaiPr_e7:39:2f (38:59:f9:e7:39:2f)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Source: D-LinkIn_2f:a4:a4 (14:d6:4d:2f:a4:a4)
        Address: D-LinkIn_2f:a4:a4 (14:d6:4d:2f:a4:a4)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Type: IP (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 85.134.37.196 (85.134.37.196), Dst: 192.168.0.101 (192.168.0.101)
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)
    Total Length: 52
    Identification: 0x8b63 (35683)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .1.. .... = Don't fragment: Set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 58
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0x7909 [correct]
        [Good: True]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 85.134.37.196 (85.134.37.196)
    Destination: 192.168.0.101 (192.168.0.101)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: http (80), Dst Port: 51714 (51714), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0
    Source port: http (80)
    Destination port: 51714 (51714)
    [Stream index: 5205]
    Sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
    Acknowledgement number: 1    (relative ack number)
    Header length: 32 bytes
    Flags: 0x011 (FIN, ACK)
        000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
        ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
        .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
        .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
        .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
        .... ...1 .... = Acknowledgement: Set
        .... .... 0... = Push: Not set
        .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
        .... .... ..0. = Syn: Not set
        .... .... ...1 = Fin: Set
            [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): Connection finish (FIN)]
                [Message: Connection finish (FIN)]
                [Severity level: Chat]
                [Group: Sequence]
    Window size value: 114
    [Calculated window size: 14592]
    [Window size scaling factor: 128]
    Checksum: 0xd1f9 [validation disabled]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
    Options: (12 bytes)
        No-Operation (NOP)
        No-Operation (NOP)
        Timestamps: TSval 1723049647, TSecr 1723044620
            Kind: Timestamp (8)
            Length: 10
            Timestamp value: 1723049647
            Timestamp echo reply: 1723044620

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
  94688 211.305660  192.168.0.101         85.134.37.196         TCP      66     51714 > http [FIN, ACK] Seq=1127 Ack=2 Win=14656 Len=0 TSval=30409384 TSecr=1723049647

Frame 94688: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits)
    Arrival Time: Nov  7, 2012 22:55:18.087932000 EET
    Epoch Time: 1352321718.087932000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000264000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000452000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 211.305660000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 94688
    Frame Length: 66 bytes (528 bits)
    Capture Length: 66 bytes (528 bits)
    [Frame is marked: True]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ip:tcp]
    [Coloring Rule Name: HTTP]
    [Coloring Rule String: http || tcp.port == 80]
Ethernet II, Src: HonHaiPr_e7:39:2f (38:59:f9:e7:39:2f), Dst: D-LinkIn_2f:a4:a4 (14:d6:4d:2f:a4:a4)
    Destination: D-LinkIn_2f:a4:a4 (14:d6:4d:2f:a4:a4)
        Address: D-LinkIn_2f:a4:a4 (14:d6:4d:2f:a4:a4)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Source: HonHaiPr_e7:39:2f (38:59:f9:e7:39:2f)
        Address: HonHaiPr_e7:39:2f (38:59:f9:e7:39:2f)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Type: IP (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.0.101 (192.168.0.101), Dst: 85.134.37.196 (85.134.37.196)
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)
    Total Length: 52
    Identification: 0x4e24 (20004)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .1.. .... = Don't fragment: Set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0xb048 [correct]
        [Good: True]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 192.168.0.101 (192.168.0.101)
    Destination: 85.134.37.196 (85.134.37.196)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51714 (51714), Dst Port: http (80), Seq: 1127, Ack: 2, Len: 0
    Source port: 51714 (51714)
    Destination port: http (80)
    [Stream index: 5205]
    Sequence number: 1127    (relative sequence number)
    Acknowledgement number: 2    (relative ack number)
    Header length: 32 bytes
    Flags: 0x011 (FIN, ACK)
        000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
        ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
        .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
        .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
        .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
        .... ...1 .... = Acknowledgement: Set
        .... .... 0... = Push: Not set
        .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
        .... .... ..0. = Syn: Not set
        .... .... ...1 = Fin: Set
            [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): Connection finish (FIN)]
                [Message: Connection finish (FIN)]
                [Severity level: Chat]
                [Group: Sequence]
    Window size value: 229
    [Calculated window size: 14656]
    [Window size scaling factor: 64]
    Checksum: 0x3c7e [validation disabled]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
    Options: (12 bytes)
        No-Operation (NOP)
        No-Operation (NOP)
        Timestamps: TSval 30409384, TSecr 1723049647
            Kind: Timestamp (8)
            Length: 10
            Timestamp value: 30409384
            Timestamp echo reply: 1723049647
    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
        [This is an ACK to the segment in frame: 94686]
        [The RTT to ACK the segment was: 0.000452000 seconds]
```

Comment: I am seeing this as well, using chrome and a local version of app engine as the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My specific issue was solved by upgrading from Varnish 3.0.2 to 3.0.3.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, Adblock was denying the request (because it was a Twitter request and I block most Twitter things).

Comment: God, I always overlook my browser plugins while debugging. Here, take my upvote.

Comment: Same. It took me like half an hour to debug that :(.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting this exact problem in Chrome and for me it was the Offline Cache that was causing trouble.

I have an asp.net html5 application designed for mobile usage with offline support. So I hade the manifest attribute like this:

```html
<html manifest="Manifest.ashx">
```

And I had an ashx handler that served the manifest file dynamically. For developing  I had deleted the the manifest attribute on the main page but I had another page that was seldom used that had the manifest attribute. The latest files in the project (one image, and two js-files) had not been added to the manifest. When I visited the other page and went back to the main page the files missing in the manifest was starting to fail in the logs, no friendly error message, just type: pending and "failed". And this was just testing on Chrome on the desktop, no going offline.

Adding the files to the manifest list solved the problem for me.