# What kind of network error is Chrome encountering when 'Status = (failed)' or 'Status = (canceled)'

Tags: google-chrome, get, request, status, openx

I'm trying to send requests to google ads server and openx but they fails in the browser and I cant figure out why. There are times that the requests pass but most of the time they fails. The behaviour is random and I cant understand why they fails sometime. I run this in clean browser with no extensions (like Ad blocker etc.)

This is how the output in my chrome network tab looks like:

```
Name    Method  Status      Type                Initiator   Size    Time
...     POST    200         application/json    odap.js:2   543 B   188 ms  
...     GET     200         image/png           odap.js:2   439 B   4 ms    
...     POST    200         application/json    odap.js:2   1.7 KB  301 ms  
...     GET     200         image/gif           Other       7.4 KB  4 ms    
...     GET     (canceled)                      Other       0 B     76 ms   
...     GET     (failed)                        Other       0 B     34 ms   
...     GET     200         image/gif           Other       316 B   40 ms   
...     POST    302         application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

This is screenshot of my chrome network tab - http://postimg.org/image/7zrm1nhln/

Comment: Please edit the image or the error codes in the question itself. If the link dies your question dies with it! Congratulations on your first question!

Comment: Stackoverflow says that I need to have at least 10 raiting for uploading image to my question.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Try to copy/paste the errors then maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What kind of network error is Chrome encountering when 'Status = (failed)' and 'Type = undefined'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125784/what-kind-of-network-error-is-chrome-encountering-when-status-failed-and)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does status=canceled for a resource mean in Chrome Developer Tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Answer (score 1):

**Status = cancelled**

- [What does status=canceled for a resource mean in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools)

**Status = failed**

- [What kind of network error is Chrome encountering when 'Status = (failed)' and 'Type = undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125784/what-kind-of-network-error-is-chrome-encountering-when-status-failed-and)